# Martingale and conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, martingales

I am new in Martingale Theory and i am struggling to understand this stochastic process.
As far as i know (if i am right) that a martingale is process of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, such that $E[X|Y=y]$ remains the same in any time of the process.

My question is: How the formula for the discrete conditional expectation is : $E[X|Y=y]=\frac{E[X_{ \mathbf{I}}(Y)]}{P(Y)}$ is being used in order to calculate thing like :

Let $X_{n},n=  1,\dots $ be  an  i.i.d.  sequence  with  mean $μ$ and  variance $\sigma^{2} < \infty$.   Let $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ be  the  Borel $\sigma$-algebra  on $\mathbb{R}_{n}$.   Then $$S_{n}−\mu n=\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n }X_{k}−\mu n$$  is a martingale.
And then he/she states that "Indeed $S_{n}$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_{n}$", and :

\begin{align*}
E[Sn+1−(n+1)μ|\mathcal{F}_{n}]&=E[Xn+1−μ+Sn−nμ|\mathcal{F}_{n}]\\
&=E[Xn+1−μ|\mathcal{F}_{n}] +E[Sn−nμ|\mathcal{F}_{n}]a\\
&=E[Xn+1−μ] +Sn−nμ\\
&=Sn−nμ.
\end{align*}

More specific:

**Question 1 :** How the conditional expectation has been used in line 1?

**Question 2 :** Again in line 1 : From where the $Sn+1−(n+1)μ$ came from ?

I am sorry for my poor understanding of martingale. Hope someone makes me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have defined a martingale in the first pargaraph doesn't make sense. You have to index the process using a 'time' variable before you can write down the definition.

Let $Y_n=S_n-n\mu$. By definition of a martingale $(Y_n)$ is  a martingale if $E(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)=Y_n$ for each $n$.

$E(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)=E(S_{n+1}-\mu (n+1)|\mathcal F_n)$ by defintion of $Y_{n+1}$. Now $S_{n+1}-\mu (n+1)$ can be written as $S_n-n\mu +(X_{n+1}-\mu)$. So $E(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)=E(S_{n+1}-\mu (n+1)|\mathcal F_n)=E(S_n-n\mu|\mathcal F_n)+E(X_{n+1}-\mu|\mathcal F_n) $. In the first term use the fact that $S_n-n\mu$ is already measurable w.r.t $\mathcal F_n$ so it is its own conditional expectation. In the second term use the fact that $X_{n+1}-\mu$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n$ so the conditional expectation is $E(X_{n+1}-\mu)=\mu-\mu=0$.

Comment: So we take the first upward time increment and we subtract it from the last one : $E[Y_{n+1}-Y_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Does the opposite is ok to do it ? For example : $E[Y_{n} -Y_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1} ]$?

Comment: The martingale condition is equivalent to $E([Y_n-Y_{n-1}]|\mathcal F_n)=0$.

Comment: Understood.Final question :  How you did this ? $S_{n+1}-\mu (n+1)$ can be written as $S_n-n\mu +(X_{n+1}-\mu)$

Comment: Simple algebra: $S_{n+1}=S_n +X_{n+1}$ by definition.

Comment: Having said that, now if i want to prove that $$S^{2}_{n}-n\sigma^{2}$$ is a martingale all i have to do is :$$S^{2}_{n+1}-(n+1)\sigma^{2}$$ which $$S^{2}_{n+1} = S^{2}_{n}+ X_{n+1}$$ in order to calculate $$E[ S^{2}_{n}-n\sigma^{2} + [X_{n+1} - (n+1)\sigma^{2} ]   ]$$ right ?